# Saving a frame/picture using Tango Camera

Tags: google-project-tango

I have a question. Is there a way to take a picture, or save current frame while a tango app is running and how can i achieve this kind of behaviour

Comment: I have found something, there is a callback in the ITangoVideoOverlay interface, there is a method which is called each frame and from a paramater (imageBuffer) u can retrieve a byte array wich contains information in  YUV standard format about every frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used ReadPixels and gave as parameters the dimensions of the screen; it worked in Unity